# Split function always returns empty array [Browserstack, IOS devices]

Tags: javascript, ios, browserstack

Steps for reproducing:

1. Open any site using any IOS device on Browserstack
2. Open DevTool
3. Execute in console smth like `"bla bla bla".split(" ")`

Expected: `(3) ["bla", "bla", "bla"]`

In fact: `[]`

Have anyone ever bumped into this issue?

Comment: I think that you should contact Browserstack's support, as if it's a bug with their application they're the ones who should know.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a limitation of the iOS Dev Tools on BrowserStack. However, you should be able to get the expected output by executing the command - console.log("bla bla bla".split(" "))

[image]